# Fonts appear in fc-match and fc-list but not in gnome-terminal preferences

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal, fontconfig

I installed https://github.com/powerline/fonts on my computer so that I could use the agnoster theme in oh-my-zsh. I went to change the font on my computer, and couldn't find it. To make sure I wasn't crazy, I ran `fc-match "Fira Mono for Powerline"` and got back `FuraMono Regular Powerline.otf: "Fira Mono for Powerline" "Regular"`, which is what I was expecting. gnome-font-viewer sees it, as does all of the other applications on my computer. What am I missing?